# How do I translate the position of a moving point according to a reference point?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, scipy-spatial

Given two moving points/particles with positions in cartesian coordinates x, y, z as a function of time as given bellow, how do I center one of the points and calculate the resulting positions of the second point while maintaining their relative distance and orientation constant?

```py
# Given the absolute positions of point 1 (p1) and point 2 (p2): 
p1 = [
    [7.74, 9.48, 9.61],
    [7.02, 8.83, 9.42],
    [7.91, 9.08, 9.56],
    [8.61, 8.92, 9.50],
    [8.87, 9.35, 9.63],
    [7.77, 9.83, 9.86]
]

p2 = [
    [7.90, 10.48, 10.2],
    [8.30, 10.74, 9.59],
    [8.23, 10.24, 9.86],
    [8.15, 10.42, 9.91],
    [8.05, 10.44, 9.92],
    [8.4, 10.78, 10.04]
]

# Center p1. It does not necessarily have to be at (0, 0, 0). 
p1 = [
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0]
]

# Translate p2 so its relative position (distance & orientation) relative to p1 remains constant. 
p2 = []
```

Intuitively, I'd try to find translation and rotation matrices for the conversion. I looked at `scipy.spatial` but could not find a solution to my problem (that I could understand, at least).

How would I try to solve this problem?

Edit 1: 
Both points move supposedly independently from each other, so their distance+orientation should not be constant. My goal is to test that supposition: do the points exert any influence on each other.
Specifically, I want to calculate the density of point 2 relative to point  1, but for this calculation to make sense I need point 1 fixed first. Hope this further clarifies the problem.

Comment: I don't understand: the coordinates given for point 1 and point 2 suggest that the relative distance and orientation of the 2 points is not constant. Could you please clarify?

Comment: That's correct. Both points move supposedly independently from each other, so their distance+orientation should not be constant. My goal is to test that supposition: do the points exert any influence on each other.  
Specifically, I want to calculate the density of point 2 relative to point  1, but for this calculation to make sense I need point 1 fixed first. Hope this clarifies the problem. I also edited my question to add this clarification.

Comment: Do you not simply need to subtract `p1` from `p2` element-wise?

Comment: I just did some testing and it seems like you are right. I really did not expect the problem to be this straightforward. I'll look further into this but for now, it seems like all I have to do is just element-wise subtractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit cryptic if you are unfamiliar with linear algebra but in essence you can manipulate the vectors to calculate the length and cylindrical rotation of the vector between the two points. It would go like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

p1 = [
    [7.74, 9.48, 9.61],
    [7.02, 8.83, 9.42],
    [7.91, 9.08, 9.56],
    [8.61, 8.92, 9.50],
    [8.87, 9.35, 9.63],
    [7.77, 9.83, 9.86]
]

p2 = [
    [7.90, 10.48, 10.2],
    [8.30, 10.74, 9.59],
    [8.23, 10.24, 9.86],
    [8.15, 10.42, 9.91],
    [8.05, 10.44, 9.92],
    [8.4, 10.78, 10.04]
]

# Transform lists to arrays
a1, a2 = np.array(p1), np.array(p2)
# Get vector from p1 to p2
v = a2 - a1

# Get the norm of all vectors p1p2, i.e. the distance between p1 and p2
n = linalg.norm(v, axis=1)
# Normalize the vectors if need be
unit_v = v / n[:, None]

# Normalize the vectors in xy plane
unit_v_xy = (v / linalg.norm(v[:, 0:2], axis=1)[:, None])[:, 0:2]
# Get angles modulo pi in xy plane
xy_angles = np.column_stack((np.arccos(unit_v_xy[:, 0]), np.arcsin(unit_v_xy[:, 1])))

# Get pitch angle, i.e. angle between vector and z axis
pitch_angles = np.arccos(np.dot(unit_v, np.array([0, 0, 1])))
```

Comment: It is still not clear to me, however, how you go from these results to calculating the new coordinates for p2? I followed up on the comments above and did an element-wise subtraction of p2 by p1, and the results seem ok, but since this is a scientific project I'd rather know for certain that what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: If you just need to know whether the points are moving relative to each other then comparing p2-p1 at different time t is sufficient. If you want to know how the points are moving relative to each other, then I tried to give a few suggestions about how to get the distance and angles to describe the movement. Don't bother with it if you don't need it.